# Set datatemplate for Infragistics ContentPane

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, infragistics

I am using Infragistics TabGroupPane in one of my user controls. I use MVVM for bindings. When I use this usercontrol in another usercontrol, I want to set the DataTemplate for Infragistics ContentPane. How can I do that?

Below is the code I am using, but it doesnot work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type infragistics:ContentPane}">
        <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Content, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn_1" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.IsReorderSupported}"  
            CanUserSortColumns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.IsColSortable}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type infragistics:PaneHeaderPresenter}">
        <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Content, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn_1" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.IsReorderSupported}"  
            CanUserSortColumns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.IsColSortable}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Name="someContent" Content="{Binding InfraTabs}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

</Grid>
```

NOTE: InfraTabs is a collection of ContentPane.

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still looking for answer, but I have found a workaround for this problem:

WORKAROUND: I created a dummy InfraTabViewModel and assigned ContentPane's content to that ViewModel. In my view, I added a datatemplate for InfraTabViewModel and it works!
Below is the workaround code:
In View:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:InfraTabViewModel}">
        <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding DGView, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
            SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn_1" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.IsReorderSupported}"  
            CanUserSortColumns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.IsColSortable}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In ViewModel:

```
    public class InfraTabViewModel
{
    public object DGView { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<ContentPane> InfraTabs = new ObservableCollection<ContentPane>();

    public ObservableCollection<ContentPane> InfraTabs
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        //Code to populate the dataTable

        ContentPane cp = new ContentPane();
        cp.Header = "Some DataGrid";
        cp.Content = dt.AsDataView(); // does not work.
        cp.Content = new InfraTabViewModel { DGView = dt.AsDataView() }; // works.
    }
}
```